# Line between first and last point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing a chart in Matplotlib , using the plot(x, y) command where x and y are arrays.  In the resulting chart I have the first and last point connected by a line.  How to avoid the first and last point to be connected ?

Comment: What exact code are you using - i.e. the plot command - please provide a small example that shows your problem.

Comment: That is not the default behavior in matplotlib. y = arange(100)
y = arange(100,0,-1)
len x
len y
plot(x,y) does not connect the first and last points.

Comment: It's possible that your x values are not sorted, or that the last x (ie. x[-1]) coincides with the first x, x[0].

Comment: Please show use code and data which replicate this problem.

Comment: I just had the same issue happen to me and found that using the GTK back end was the issue. That is: `matplotlib.use('GTK')` would exhibit the behavior, while `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` would not. I think this only happened after an update (I'm using debian).

Comment: ozbob, you should put this as an answer, I'm using -X forwarding on my SHH session, and that solved my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problem as you can see:

BEFORE
[image]

I just sorted `x` using this:

```
x = sorted(x)
```

And the line disappeared as you can see: (But the data is disturbed due to sorting).

AFTER SORTING
[image]

You must also make sure the respective `y` values should also be accordingly arranged for the sorted `x`. The final output is here:

FIXED
[image]