# Matlab: remove line between first and last Points

Tags: matlab

I am plotting data vs time, however there is a line that connects the first and last points, how do I get rid of this line?

Relevant code:

```
data = load('AMT_CO2.txt');
time = data(:,1);
avg = data(:,2);
plot(time, avg);
```

[image]
    plot(time(1:end-1), avg(1:end-1))

Please note that this question has been asked here:
[Line between first and last point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540349/line-between-first-and-last-point)
however, this doesn't have an answer

There is also a question: [Removing the line between two specific data points in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754939/removing-the-line-between-two-specific-data-points-in-matlab)
however, I tried not plotting the last point and I get the same line

Comment: @ manateejoe  Erman Gungor's answer is the right thing to do. Check your data to see if it repeats (x,y) pairs at the end. Matlab would not arbitrarily decide to draw a line between data like this. There has to be a place in your data where the next data point is back at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could sort the time vector.

`[time, dum] = sort(time);
avg = avg(dum);`

Or remove repeated values:

`[time, dum, ~] = unique(time);
avg = avg(dum);`

However, be careful because the repeated point could be caused by data corruption or something similar.

Comment: Thank you! `[time,dum] = sort(time); avg = avg(dum)` worked